# jaxb unmarshall child @XmlIDREF

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, idref

I have class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "customerOrder", propOrder = {
    "demandsUuid",
    "invoicesOutUuid",
    "paymentsUuid",
    "customerOrderPosition",
    "purchaseOrdersUuid"
}) 
public  class CustomerOrder extends LegendEntity {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "sourceAgentUuid")
    @XmlIDREF
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "IDREF")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(XmlAdapterTest.class)
    protected Object sourceAgentUuid;
....
```

Also Agent class for sourceAgentUuid field

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "agent", propOrder = {
    "attribute",
    "requisite",
    "contact",
    "contactPerson",
    "agentNewsItem",
    "tags"
})
@XmlSeeAlso({
    Company.class
})
public class Agent
    extends LegendEntity
{

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    @XmlID
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "ID")
    protected String uuid;
```

And unmarshalling xml snipetpets

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customerOrder deliveryPlannedMoment="2014-04-23T16:10:00+04:00" reservedSum="0.0" stateUuid="44b3fca5-a2b3-11e3-31b2-002590a28eca" targetAgentUuid="9a3c7d6b-4245-11e3-24c6-7054d21a8d1e" 
sourceAgentUuid="ef0b03de-c95b-11e3-9183-002590a28eca" sourceStoreUuid="b05ed064-8743-11e3-0c1a-002590a28eca" 
applicable="true" moment="2014-04-21T17:50:00+04:00" payerVat="true" rate="1.0" vatIncluded="true" created="2014-04-21T17:50:44.142+04:00" createdBy="it@erms" name="440" updated="2014-04-22T12:19:56.472+04:00" updatedBy="it@erms" readMode="SELF" changeMode="NONE">
                <accountUuid>5f65cc9e-3708-11e3-bf9a-7054d21a8d1e</accountUuid>
                <accountId>5f65cc9e-3708-11e3-bf9a-7054d21a8d1e</accountId>
                <uuid>ef1267b8-c95b-11e3-aeb4-002590a28eca</uuid>
                <groupUuid>9a3ad96b-4245-11e3-010e-7054d21a8d1e</groupUuid>
                <groupId>9a3ad96b-4245-11e3-010e-7054d21a8d1e</groupId>
                <code>440</code>
                <externalcode>440</externalcode>
```

When I try to unmarshall

```
JAXBElement poe =  (JAXBElement)u.unmarshal( new FileInputStream( "org_order.xml" ) );
CustomerOrder co=(CustomerOrder)poe.getValue();
System.out.println(co.getSourceAgentUuid());
```

result null (but all other not @XmlIDREF field unmarshalled ok)

How I can get ef0b03de-c95b-11e3-9183-002590a28eca result ?

**I had create test class for simply.
Why output is null?**

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlID;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlIDREF;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.CollapsedStringAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

public class TestMarshall {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // marshal();
            unmarshal();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void marshal() throws Exception {
        CustomerOrder co = new CustomerOrder();
        Agent a = new Agent();
        a.setUuid("sdfsdf");
        co.setSourceAgentUuid(a);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(CustomerOrder.class,
                Agent.class);
        Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
        m.marshal(co, System.out);
    }
    public static void unmarshal() throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(CustomerOrder.class,
                Agent.class);
        Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        String testXML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><customerOrder sourceAgentUuid=\"sdfsdf\"/>";
        CustomerOrder poe = (CustomerOrder) u
                .unmarshal(new ByteArrayInputStream(testXML.getBytes()));
        CustomerOrder co = poe;
        System.out.println("sourceAgentUuid= " + co.getSourceAgentUuid());
    }
}
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "agent")
class Agent {
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    @XmlID
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "ID")
    protected String uuid;

    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

}
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(name = "customerOrder")
class CustomerOrder {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "sourceAgentUuid")
    @XmlIDREF
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "IDREF")
    protected Object sourceAgentUuid;

    public Object getSourceAgentUuid() {
        return sourceAgentUuid;
    }
    public void setSourceAgentUuid(Object sourceAgentUuid) {
        this.sourceAgentUuid = sourceAgentUuid;
    }

}
```

Comment: Not enough information. We need to see the XML and Java code for the referenced "source agent uuid", especially the @XmlID that ought to be there.

Comment: I add test class to the end of question. Can you help why print null?

Comment: Can't help you, still no valid XML sample showing two complete elements: CustomerOrder and Agent.

Comment: Agent not element node, that is attribute of CustomerOrder

Comment: Thats valid xml        String testXML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><customerOrder sourceAgentUuid=\"sdfsdf\"/>";

Comment: Ah, please read *carefully* what I wrote in my answer: if there is no XML element for the Agent (with @uuid="sdfsdf", the sourceAgentUuid remains null! I already wrote that - more than once!

Comment: sorry, may be exist any custom way to init element for example from another source...

Comment: You'd need a mapping of the Agent ids to the CustomerOrder ids and a data set of the Agent objects, and then you could insert the references. OR, change the agent uuid to String and resolve in the getter.

Comment: I can't map  Agent ids to the CustomerOrder ids because any time it diferent. Also i can,t change  agent uuid to String  because use third party xsd.

Comment: With XmlID all work fine, but class my entity class generated with XmlIDREF. How i can generate class annotated with XmlID ?

Comment: https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_4_3_1-Assembling-Data-with-Links-ID-IDREF.html#Assembling%20Data%20with%20Links%20%28ID,%20IDREF%29

Comment: The following example will help explain `@XmlID` and `@XmlIDREF`:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-shared-references-xmlid-and.html

Answer (score 2):

An @XmlIDREF plus its counterpart @XmlID are "XMLized pointers" that *appear* as strings in the XML text. JAXB matches such value pairs and resolves matching references into nice object references.

So, after unmarshalling, you won't see the strings from the XML file; the

```
Object sourceAgentUuid
```

(in your case) will either contain a reference to that "source agent" object (if there is such an XML element with its @XmlID set to that value) or null otherwise.

Comment: I whant that after unmarshal field Object sourceAgentUuid was initialize as object of my Agent class whith initialized field Uuid from xml.

Comment: Where is the XML element for the Agent object? Please post complete & syntactically correct XML elements. What is there now is garbage.

Comment: I add test class to the end of question. Can you help why print null?